# Applying dplyr's tally over large amount of columns to create codebook

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe ov 100+ variables and I would like to create a codebook to see the frequencies of each variable (and ideally output this to excel).  Right now, I'm using the following code:

```
freq_fun <- function(var){
  var <- enquo(var)
  frequencies <- raw %>% group_by(group, !!var) %>% tally()
  return(frequencies)
}
```

I added in the return in the hopes that looping by column names would at least show me the output but this was unsuccessful.

At this point, my plan is to do the following:

```
for(i in colnames(rawxl[,9:107])){
  assign(paste0(i,"freq"), freq_queue(!!i))
}
```

output each dataframe to a csv and then copy and paste into one excel doc.  This is undesirable for obvious reasons, but I can't see a clear way around it.  What is a better way to do this?

Comment: Please provide a sample data and the expected output format.

Comment: The data cannot be shared.  Both grouping variables are factor variables, as are almost all of the other variables.  Output is a typical codebook format whereby it gives frequencies of a variable, however in this case it is grouped by the grouping variable.